# Importing Packages to .wls without shadow definitions and context specification

Tags: import, packages, scripting, command-line

I am trying to import a package that works correctly when I use it in a notebook in a wolframscript .wls.  I get a weird shadowing problem, however.

Here is a minimal working example `test.wls`, using the example from the `Needs` documentation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript -print All

Needs["ComputerArithmetic`"]

Ulp[1000.]
```

after `chmod +x test.wls` the result of running it is

```
> ./test.wls

Ulp::shdw: Symbol Ulp appears in multiple contexts {ComputerArithmetic`, Global`}; 
definitions in context ComputerArithmetic` may shadow or be shadowed by other
definitions.
Global`Ulp[1000.]
```

However, when I copy and paste the two non-shebang lines of code from test.wls into a notebook, I get the correct result.  The same thing happens with my custom package.

I tried runnning `wolframscript -code '$Path'` and the directory that contains my package is there, so it cannot be a screwed up path.

If I change the final line of my script to

```
ComputerArithmetic`Ulp[1000.]
```

I get as output `1.1368683772161603*^-13`, and the same fix works for my own package.

*Question*: what is going on here, and what is a good workaround so that I don't have to specify the context of every custom package procedure and variable?

Comment: For completeness, I have `$Version=="12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)"`

Comment: I guess I should also say that I have `wolframscript --version` `WolframScript 1.2.0 for MacOSX-x86-64`.

Comment: It seems to be fine if you remove `-print All` and use e.g. `Echo` inside.

Comment: You're right, that is a solution.  But the documentation https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/wolframscript.html suggests I should be able to use `-print All` (or maybe `all`) to get everything printed.  In my "actual" script, rather than my mwe, making this change would be very very annoying.

Comment: This script still fails, `WolframScript 1.9.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)` with `13.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)`.

Comment: This script still fails, with `WolframScript 1.9.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit)` and `$Version == "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)"`.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a version of the script that works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript -print All -run \'Needs[\"ComputerArithmetic`\"]\'

Ulp[1000.]
```

This is a limitation of `-print All` that we probably should either document or find a fix for, though the latter is rather challenging.  When executing a script normally or using `-print`, wolframscript can essentially tell the kernel to just `Get` the script file and print or not the value returned by `Get`.  But for `-print All`, wolframscript effectively has to import the script prior to executing it to get all the individual expressions.  This means the all the symbols are created prior to the `Needs` evaluating, and the package symbols end up in the wrong context.  Using the `-run` option to the kernel (without lots of shell escapes) tells the kernel to load the package prioir to doing anything, so the symbols are created in the right context.

**Update**

After thinking about this some more, it probably doesn't actually have to import the file first--it's probably just doing that for efficiency.  It could read it in one expression at a time, evaluate the expression, and print the result.  This would be slower, but produce more accurate results.  I'll file a bug about this.

Comment: Why does it have to import the script prior to execution, rather than reading it line-by-line (or similar) and executing it on the fly?